# Importing csv, tab delimited and excel files into c#

Tags: c#, file, csv

I'm developing an Excel import routine which is using OLEDB to read the file. Can I just reuse my code to do the same thing for csv and tab delimited files by just changing the connection string, and what would the strings be?